# HTML not rendered inside tooltip from react-tooltip

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I used tooltip form `react-tooltip` and I want to inside tooltip put some `HTML` tags. How to manage this? I don't find any information in [react-tooltip site](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/).
For now I create Tooltip:

```
const TooltipConst = props => {
if (props.tooltip && props.id) {
    const tooltip = <Tooltip id={props.id + 'Tooltip'}>
        <div> render(){props.tooltip} </div>
    </Tooltip>;
    return (
        <OverlayTrigger
            overlay={tooltip}
            placement="top"
            delayShow={500}
            delayHide={1000}
        >
            {props.children}
        </OverlayTrigger>
    );
}
return <div>{props.children}</div>;
```

};

And when pass as tooltip some string with `HTML` they not rendered. Any advice?
I try also put as object, for example `<span><p>some text</p> Some text </span>`, but it return not text but something like `Object[]` as tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add html in ReactTooltip, like html button or other html tags in it. And wants to show on click.

```
<div id={row.index} className="text-center">
     <a data-tip={'dummystring'} data-event={'click focus'}
      data-for={'tooltip'}>Show tooltip</a>
     <ReactTooltip id={'tooltip'} effect="solid"
           clickable={true} place="right"
           getContent={function() {
           return (
                <div>
                   <span>Some text</span>
                   <Button 
                   onClick={()=>alert('clicked')}>
                   Click Me </Button>
                </div>
          )
    }}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tooltip = (<Tooltip id={props.id + 'Tooltip'}>
    <div> render(){props.tooltip} </div>
</Tooltip>);
```

this is by their officiel documentation

also if you want to render html through props you should use dangerouslySetHTML => see  React's documentation

Comment: Also render as `render(){props.tooltip}` or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={props.tooltip}`
I think problem lies in that I put content of tooltip to `OverlayTrigger` and this component not manage and treat content as raw string.

Comment: How about function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: props.tooltip};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-tooltip library.
Pass a prop `html={true}` to  `<ReactTooltip />` as  `<ReactTooltip html={true} />` [for more information refer this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had a look into the documentation and they now have a `data-html` prop to detect if you want render html markup, something like this:

```
<ToolTipData data-tip={text} data-html={text.indexOf('</') > -1}>
    {children}
  </ToolTipData>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not super obvious from the docs but even if you are wanting HTML to be rendered inside the tooltip, it still needs to be in a string (wrap your HTML in backticks). Setting the html prop on the tooltip under the hood sets dangerouslySetInnerHtml on the string you pass in.

```
const inner = `<p>I'm html in a string</p><p>Same</p>`
```

and your tooltip:

```
 <ReactTooltip
    html={true}
    id={"tooltip"}
    place="right"
    type="dark"
    effect="solid"
  >
    {inner}
  </ReactTooltip>
```